# C# revert to previous version

Tags: c#, version, revert

My developer did not save the stable version of C# application( lets say v12) that we are developing. Now after bunch of enhancements we are at V20,  but the application has become crap at v20. So I asked the developer to revert back to v12, but the developer says he cant as he did not save that version. Fortunately he made a .dll file of v12 to test. So I asked him to de-compile v12 dll and revert the  code by looking at decompiled code as reference.Despite couple of attempts he was not able to restore and recreate stable v12.

Can someone please advise if there is a way in C# to revert to previous version ?

My application is total mess and the developer just cant fix it . I am really frustrated and concerned that months of development work could go to waste

I am not sure if he is taking me for a ride or genuinely there is no way to revert to previous version.

ps: I do not have any coding background.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, lesson learned, you'll know what to look for the next time you hire a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with C#. Good development practice is to use a version control system like SVN, Git, Mercurial etc. Reverting any previous versions is not a problem when using a VCS.

If your "developer" did not do this but just keeps a single set of files for developing, there is no way of reverting. Decompilation of the .dll and start development from there is a poor choice.

Comment: Just as an addition, with version control you always can look up what has changed. So you can play around with the changes until you find the bad ones.

Comment: oh nooo
I spent 8 months on this project .

is there no other way to revert the changes .. can someone please advise ?

Comment: I know you want to hear there is some magical way to restore any data - but there just isn't. At least, this is not a C# question, but rather a data backup question. If your programmer did not do any backup, and did not use any backup or VCS software, the data is gone. Deal with it.

Comment: -( thats really sad to hear. Thanks everyone for the input.